# Dynamic Bootstrap popover shows only first time

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a strange problem with bootstrap popover, the popover is created dynamically on a button click it creates the product and then loads content from an ajax url into it.

The popover should be destroyed on close but I think that might not be, on the first click it loads fine but on subsequent clicks it does not show but I can see it making multiple load requests in the background.

e.g. on the first click I see one call being made in console, on the second 2, on the 3rd 5 and so on.

```
          $('.quickBuy').on('click', function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            var el = $(this);
            var productId = $(this).attr('data-productId');
            var URI = '@Url.Action("QuickBuy", "Home")' + '?id=' + productId;
            var content;
            var updatePopover;


            $(el).popover({
                title: 'Quick Buy ' + productId + '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle bidstreetclose"></span>',
                container: 'body',
                placement: 'right',
                html: true,
                content: '<div id="' + productId + 'content" style="width:250px; height:140px;"> loading...</div>'
            });

            $(el).on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
                $('.popover').find('.bidstreetclose').on('click', function (e) {
                    $(el).popover('hide');
                });
                $('#' + auctionId + 'content').load(URI);
                updatePopover = setInterval(function () {
                    $.get('/Ajax/GetProductInfoById?id=' + auctionId, function (data) {
                    });

                }, 2000);
            });

            $(el).on('hidden.bs.popover', function () {
            clearInterval(updatePopover);
                $(el).popover('destroy');
                $('.popover').remove();
            });
            $(el).popover('show');

            $('#submit').on('click', function (e) {
                $(document).submitQuickBuy(this);
            });

        });
```

assistance much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are attaching an event handler everytime 'Quick Buy' button is clicked. You may have to move the event binding code for popups outside the button click handler or use off() (http://api.jquery.com/off/) to detach the existing event handlers and bind a new one.

```
$(el).off('shown.bs.popover').on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
});
```

Comment: Off doesn't seema to make much difference and the eventbinding code needs to be inside the click handler as it uses local data to that event.